# Imported module not found

Tags: python, importerror

I am writing a python script which requires pywin module and I have already installed them but the vscode is showing "Import "pywin32" or "pywin32com" could not be resolved". What am I missing here?

```
# import win32com.client
import pywin32
import pywin32com
# Open a Word application instance
word = pywin32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

# Open the desired document in Word
doc = word.Documents.Open("D:/files/test.doc")

# Loop through all paragraphs in the document
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
  # Check if the current paragraph is selected
 if paragraph.Range.Information(pywin32com.client.constants.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 0:
    # Print the selected paragraph's text
    print(paragraph.Range.Text)
```

The above code is the code I am trying to execute. The pip list in showing the following list:

```
numpy             1.23.5      
pandas-stubs      1.5.2.221124
Pillow            9.3.0       
pip               22.3.1      
PyPDF2            2.12.1
pypiwin32         223
pytz              2022.6
pywin32           305
setuptools        65.6.3
six               1.16.0
types-pytz        2022.6.0.1
typing_extensions 4.4.0
urllib3           1.26.13
wheel             0.38.4
```

Here it is showing that pywin32 is already installed but the import error is not resolved. Why? Any advice on the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looks like you have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. pip installed the modules for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python in vscode.

Comment: If that is the problem then how can i uninstall the older version. The app list in control panel is showing only python 3.11.0 (64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the python version you use for building the script is the same as the python version you use to run `pip install pywin32`.

When you run `pip install ...` it will show the part to the python version which is being installed, use it to compare with the python version which show when you build/debug the script.

Example of logging when installing a library (it has `python310` -> it is being installed on Python 3.10)

```
Requirement already satisfied: loguru in c:\users\ntgr\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (0.6.0)
```

Example of logging when running a script (it has `Python310` -> it is running on Python 3.10):

```
PS D:\_PROJECT\bot_hunter_5.0\hunter-5-0-bot>  & 'C:\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\NTGR\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugp
y\launcher' '56421' '--' 'd:\_PROJECT\bot_hunter_5.0\hunter-5-0-bot\bot.py
```

'